# Return more than one column from SELECT statement subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns a column as an subquery within a select statement:

```
SELECT
  t.date,
  (
  SELECT 
  COUNT(item_id)
  FROM   item i
  WHERE  t.day BETWEEN trunc(i.start_date) AND trunc(i.end_date)
  ) AS cnt
FROM   
  calendar t
```

I need to return more than one column from the embedded select statement, but running into the 'ORA-00913: too many values' error, which makes sense to me as embedded select statement shouldn't return more than one value as a column. This is where I can't figure out how to return 2 more columns. Ideally, I want my table to look like this, where I want to return the count of item_id's, item_type and sum of the area from the item table and the date from the calendar table.

| day | cnt | item_type | sum_area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-05 | 8 | M | 102.2 |
| 2023-12-05 | 15 | P | 155.3 |
| 2023-12-04 | 10 | M | 98.6 |
| 2023-12-04 | 18 | P | 160.5 |
| 2023-12-03 | 2 | M | 106.7 |
| 2023-12-03 | 13 | P | 147.2 |

Comment: Sounds like you want a JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT
    T.DATE,
    COUNT(ITEM_ID)     AS CNT,
    I.ITEM_TYPE,
    SUM(I.AREA)        AS SUM_AREA
  FROM
    CALENDAR  T
      LEFT JOIN ITEM      I 
      ON T.DAY BETWEEN TRUNC(I.START_DATE) AND TRUNC(I.END_DATE)
 GROUP BY
    T.DATE,
    I.ITEM_TYPE;
```

Comment: Thanks @Popeye. That works for what I need!